# React router 6 redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

On my main page I have a login form and I also check to see if the user is already authenticated.

If it is authenticated I would like to redirect it to other parts of the app

Something like this:

```
export default observer(function HomePage() {

    const {userStore} = useStore();

    if (userStore.isLoggedIn) return <Navigate replace to="/profile" />

    return (
        <>
             ...
        </>
    )
}
```

Now this

```
if (userStore.isLoggedIn) return <Navigate replace to="/profile" />
```

gets the application in an endless loop

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    at RouterProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53533:5)
```

How do you handle this redirect in your apps?

Comment: What you get when `consol.log(userStore.user)`? Is this all relevant code for this?

Comment: @SinisaM It's a boolean either true or false depending if there is a user in the store. If it is true I would like to redirect the user to another page.

Comment: Yes but what is returning now? Does it return boolean when you log it or something else?

Comment: I actually have a typo there, should have been `isLoggedIn` rather than `user`. I have a user object `user: User | null = null;` where `User` looks like `export interface User {
    username: string;
    token: string;
}` and a getter `get isLoggedIn() {
        return !!this.user;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it like this:

```
import { router } from "../../app/router/Routes";
```

where `rounter` is a `router = createBrowserRouter(routes);`

and then

```
if (userStore.isLoggedIn) router.navigate('/accounts');
```